# WorldWind Java 0.6 source code?

Tags: worldwind

Does anyone know where I can find the (very old) WorldWind Java source code for version 0.6?

For example: http://patmurris.blogspot.com/2009/03/worldwind-java-06-source-available.html

Comment: My GeoServer tag was removed :)  I am asking because GeoServer DDS community module uses worldwind 0.6 as a Maven dependency.  A side question would be, do you think there'd be any problem using a newer worldwind in the GeoServer DDS community module build?